# How do I add install a JAR and the java docs?

Tags: eclipse, maven

How to I do the following using **Maven**?
I downloaded the Admob android sdk from http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/download.html
I am trying to install the Jar and the java docs that come in the downloaded ZIP file
How do I install both the JAR and the Java docs into my repo? thanks
oh btw, the javadocs are not located in a JAR, they are stored in a multilevel folder format.
Thanks

Comment: I think the answer is already available to you here: http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html

Comment: @brindy sorry, I forgot to mention I am using Maven to manage my dependancies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the javadocs are not available in a remote maven repo. You have to install the **jars** into your repo. Use the Install Plugin to perform this task. [This](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/installing-secondary-artifacts.html) is what you have to do.

Comment: Thank you @Michael-O
But I am still very confused and can not get it to work.
I have used commands like:
mvn install:install-file -DartifactId=GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.1.1.jar  \
-DgroupId=com.google.ads \
-DgroupId=com.google.ads \
-Dclassifier=javadoc \
-Dfile=/Users/Dewi/Desktop/GoogleAdMobAdsSdkAndroid-4.1.1/docs

But they don't work. I really don't know what I am doing :(
More help please? help is greatly appreciated

Comment: anyone? :/
this is driving me insane

Comment: You did not read the help. It has to be a JAR file. No dirs, no zip files.

Comment: So I have to package the classes and the javadoc in to the same JAR file or? thank you

Comment: No, no. Everything has to be in a seperate JAR file.